# Placement of a Function in an ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-2

For educational purposes, I am building a clone social bookmarking service (similar to reddit). Under each 'bookmark' in the list, I'd like to show the **base domain** of the source URL (as opposed to the full URL.

I've already found a few threads on SO on how to do this, so I've gone ahead and made a class to abstract the functionality, but I'm unsure of where I should actually be calling the method.

At the moment I have my `BookmarkList` controller method passing a list of `Bookmark` objects to the view, where I'm iterating over the list. Since the `Bookmark` object doesn't have a property for storing the base URL (as I'm computing it on the fly) I can't put it inside the `Bookmark` objects before passing them to the view (and it seems wrong anyway). So should I be calling the GetDomainFromUrl method I've made from the view itself? For some reason that doesn't feel appropriate either.

I am unsure of how to fit in this functionality without breaking MVC convention.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "the Bookmark object doesn't have a property for storing the base URL (as I'm computing it on the fly)", what information is required to compute this base URL "on the fly"? Is there a reason you couldn't add a property to the Bookmark model for `BaseURL`?

Comment: @kaveman There's no reason why I can't, I was just taught that — as a general rule — it isn't the best idea to store anything that can be calculated at runtime (unless it affects performance overly). Not sure if that's the general opinion of SO, just what I've been told.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add it to the Bookmark class.  Properties can be computed, here is an example from a tutorial on asp.net mvc from msdn ([MSDN source](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)):

```
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName;
        }
    }
```

Instead of simply concatinating strings, you would call your GetDomainFromUrl method here.

IE,

```
public string BaseUrl
{
    get
    {
        return GetDomainFromUrl(this.Url);
    }
}
```

*Notice that there is not a set method defined, since you could/would be setting the Url property.*

Also, is your Url stored as a string?

If you are using the [URI class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx), you could just use this.FullUrl.Host, assuming your article's url is defined in a property called FullUrl.(also assuming that this would not defeat the point of this assignment, since you said this was for school.)

Comment: The URL is stored as a string. The purpose of the assignment was to just build the service and go through all the steps of software development, doesn't matter how I do it. I'll look into it.

Comment: Cool. I noticed in the comments to your questions that you mentioned you were taught not to store anything that can be calculated at runtime.  I agree with that statement.  What are you using to store this?  I was using entity framework for this project/tutorial, and I just confirmed that it did not create a column in the db for the FullName property.

Comment: To what @Kye mentioned in the comments: @ahartman00's answer isn't storing the `BaseURL`, as you'll see it is read-only and calls a function itself when called.

Comment: @ahartman00 I am indeed using Entity Framework. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

For very basic scenarios, or where you have full control over your models, MVC (Model, View, Controller) is a good pattern.

In my experience, you typically need additional information that is important to your views but not to your actual model. For example, a list of dropdown items to be displayed for a model property, or in your case, putting the base URL for a site for your users to see.

In this case, I like to adapt MVC to be VM-V-C (**ViewModel**, View, Controller).

Essentially, you would want to create a Bookmark ViewModel and use that when rendering your views:

BookmarkViewModel.cs:

```
public class BookmarkViewModel
{
    public string BaseUrl {get;set;}

    // + all existing bookmark properties
}
```

You can either add your base URL function right into your view model and have the view model perform the function itself, or you can do it in your controller when creating the view model.

Comment: Interesting concept, it might be overkill for its purpose though. Working in a group situation where some of the students...well, have a hard time grasping concepts, so it might be an issue.

Comment: +1 for the ViewModel concept.  Overkill in this situation; I think so, but it is a concept I have found myself using.  The examples @armen.shimoon mentioned are good, in addition: to avoid disclosing information one wouldnt want users or third party observers from knowing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options on how you could do this. I recommend storing the GetDomainFromUrl() method in the Bookmark Class. Also I recommend creating a property for the BaseUrl as well.

You can then either pass the full Url to the Bookmark object in the constructor, perform your function, and set it to the BaseUrl property.

```
class Bookmark
{
    public string BaseUrl { get; }

    public Bookmark(string url)
    {
        BaseUrl = GetDomainFromUrl(url);
    }

    private string GetDomainFromUrl(string url)
    {
        //your logic to generate BaseUrl
    }
}
```

Another alternative is to do something like the following:

```
class Bookmark
{
    private string baseUrl;

    public string BaseUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return baseUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            baseUrl = GetDomainFromUrl(value));
        }
    }

    private string GetDomainFromUrl(string url)
    {
        //your logic to generate BaseUrl
    }
}
```

and then set the BaseUrl property somplace in your code to the value of the full url, and when you do so it will perform your function and store it in your property.